# How to make buttons within a div to go to a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

im trying to make some sort of a menu for a friend.

What the code is suppose to do is the following:

When you click one of the Rainbow buttons is shows a div by toggling the visible/hidden class. So far so good, but now i want them to have buttons inside the div's that can be used to navigate through the diffrent div's.

This without success....

From rainbow A to rainbow B with "next" button is working. But only once, after that it decides to crash.... Can someone help me fix this please. Or just push me into the right direction.

I know my code is probably not the best you've ever seen but i dont worry about that to much.

Code:

HTML

```
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div id="page_2" class="pages hidden">
    <div id="rbHeader" class="triggerDiv">
        <h1 style="color: grey;"><b><i>Page: <span style="color: white;">2</span></i></b></h1>
        <p><b>Menu le Patty</b></p>
        <div id="buttonRijC">
            <button id="rbknopA" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbA" style="background-color: purple;">Rainbow A</button>
            <button id="rbknopB" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbB" style="background-color: blue;">Rainbow B</button>
            <button id="rbknopC" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbC" style="background-color: lightblue;">Rainbow C</button>
            <button id="rbknopD" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbD" style="background-color: lightgreen;">Rainbow D</button>
            <button id="rbknopE" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbE" style="background-color: green;">Rainbow E</button>
            <button id="rbknopF" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbF" style="background-color: yellow;">Rainbow F</button>
            <button id="rbknopG" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbG" style="background-color: orange;">Rainbow G</button>
            <button id="rbknopH" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbH" style="background-color: pink;">Rainbow H</button>
            <button id="rbknopI" class="rainbow_buttons" value="rbI" style="background-color: red;">Rainbow I</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="rbDivs">
            <div id="rbdivA" class="rainbow_divs hidden first" style="background-color: purple;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">A</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivB" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: blue;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">B</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivC" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: lightblue;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">C</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivD" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">D</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivE" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: green;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">E</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivF" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: yellow;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">F</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivG" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: orange;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">G</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivH" class="rainbow_divs hidden" style="background-color: pink;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">H</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>

            <div id="rbdivI" class="rainbow_divs hidden last" style="background-color: red;">
                <h1>RAINBOW <span style="color: white;">I</span></h1>
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt dignissim urna, non commodo nisi lacinia vel. Nulla facilisi. Nulla molestie faucibus lacus ut luctus. Donec aliquet, massa ac luctus tempor, odio odio ultrices sapien, gravida porta eros dolor eget enim. Sed a congue mauris. Pellentesque ornare ipsum quis odio.</p>
                <br />
                <button id="rbTerug" class="rbMenu" value="rbBack">Back to buttons</button>
                <button id="rbVorige" disabled="disabled" class="rbMenu" value="rbPrev">Prev (-1)</button>
                <button id="rbVolgende" class="rbMenu" value="rbNext">Next (+1)</button>
                <br /><br />                    
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    /* Page 2 */
/* page 2 div's */
#rbdivA, #rbdivB, #rbdivC, #rbdivD, #rbdivE, #rbdivF, #rbdivG, #rbdivH, #rbdivI {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
.rainbow_buttons {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
#rbTerug, #rbVolgende, #rbVorige {
/*  background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    border-left: 3px solid white;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    left: 25%; */
    border-left: 3px solid green;
    background-color: grey;
    color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#rbTerug:disabled, #rbVolgende:disabled, #rbVorige:disabled {
    color: red;
    cursor: no-drop;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
//Page 2 scripts
//page 2 rainbow buttons
$(function rainbowButton(){
    var $theRainbow = $(".rainbow_buttons");
    var showRainbowA = document.getElementById("rbdivA");
    var showRainbowB = document.getElementById("rbdivB");
    var showRainbowC = document.getElementById("rbdivC");
    var showRainbowD = document.getElementById("rbdivD");
    var showRainbowE = document.getElementById("rbdivE");
    var showRainbowF = document.getElementById("rbdivF");
    var showRainbowG = document.getElementById("rbdivG");
    var showRainbowH = document.getElementById("rbdivH");
    var showRainbowI = document.getElementById("rbdivI");
    var getHeader = document.getElementById("rbHeader");

    $theRainbow.click(function() {
        if(this.value == "rbA"){    
            showRainbowA.className = "visible current first";
            showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
            showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
            getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else if (this.value == "rbB") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else if (this.value == "rbC") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else if (this.value == "rbD") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last"
                getHeader.className = "hidden";             
        } else if (this.value == "rbE") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else if (this.value == "rbF") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else if (this.value == "rbG") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else if (this.value == "rbH") {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "visible current";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        } else {
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "visible current last";
                getHeader.className = "hidden";
        }
    });
});
//page 2 buttons inside hidden div's
$(function rbMenuback(){
    var $theMenu = $(".rbMenu");

    var showRainbowA = document.getElementById("rbdivA");
    var showRainbowB = document.getElementById("rbdivB");
    var showRainbowC = document.getElementById("rbdivC");
    var showRainbowD = document.getElementById("rbdivD");
    var showRainbowE = document.getElementById("rbdivE");
    var showRainbowF = document.getElementById("rbdivF");
    var showRainbowG = document.getElementById("rbdivG");
    var showRainbowH = document.getElementById("rbdivH");
    var showRainbowI = document.getElementById("rbdivI");

    var getOut = document.getElementById("rbOut");
    var getNext = document.getElementById("rbVolgende");
    var getHeader = document.getElementById("rbHeader");

    $theMenu.click(function() {
        if (this.value == "rbNext") {
            $('#rbVolgende').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden').removeClass('current')
        .next().removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible').addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#rbVolgende').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#rbVorige').attr('disabled', null);
});
        } else if (this.value == "rbPrev") {
                $('#rbVorige').click(function() {
            $('.current').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden').removeClass('current')
                        .prev().removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible').addClass('current');
                if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
                $('#rbVorige').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
            $('#rbVolgende').attr('disabled', null);
                });
        } else {
                getHeader.className = "triggerDiv visible";
                showRainbowA.className = "hidden first";
                showRainbowB.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowC.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowD.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowE.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowF.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowG.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowH.className = "hidden";
                showRainbowI.className = "hidden last";             
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle example of te code: https://jsfiddle.net/sx273azf/6/
Here you'll find a menu with 3 buttons:

show non : won't show any page

Page 2: shows the menu i need fixing on

Page 3: an example of a working code for navigation through div's/a menu

**PS: if i can change anything in my code please let me know, any help is appreciated.**

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your prev(-1) and your next(+1) buttons are what you're having the issues with?

Comment: @SimonPrice Yes you are right, at least as far is a can see, that is the area where something is going wrong

Comment: ok, there are a few things that could be improved, im just looking through the code now, but to be honest the colours you've picked at giving me a headache already and ive only been looking at them for less than 5 minutes.  However, there are a few things that could be done. Give me some time and ill do what I can for you and post an answer

Comment: @SimonPrice I didnt pick the colors myself, but feel free to change what ever you need :) Thanks for looking into it. I'll wait patiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the Next Button  like this:

On Line 182 of the Javascript in your jsfiddle I added this function:

```
var cur_rainbow = 0;
var all_rainbows = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];

function next_rainbow() {
     document.getElementById("rbdiv" + all_rainbows[cur_rainbow]).className = "hidden";
     cur_rainbow++;
     if (cur_rainbow >= all_rainbows.length) {
        cur_rainbow--;
     }
     document.getElementById("rbdiv" + all_rainbows[cur_rainbow]).className = "visible current";

}
```

The magic is in the  *+* operator.  You can combine static strings with dynamic elements by putting a + between them.

In my answer I did  `"rbdiv"  + all_rainbows[cur_rainbow]` inside of the
 `getElementById()` function --

remember that `all_rainbows` is a list of letters `[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]`
and  `cur_rainbow` is just a number  that gets increased by using `cur_rainbow++`
and then the specific letter is accessed by doing  `all_rainbows[cur_rainbow]`

Essentially I just created an array of all the different rainbow letters, then just matched the letters up with an index in the array and performed the same operation you did when clicking on the rainbowX button.

The final step was to execute the next_rainbow() function on the NEW line 213

```
next_rainbow()
```

I'll leave the rest up to you -- this is more the right direction in terms of doing operations on multiple objects